# Get selected place data from multiple Google places autocomplete in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have multiple input fields for getting location in a single page. I used   $scope.on() event to get g-places-autocomplete selected data in my controller.

```
 $scope.$on('g-places-autocomplete:select', function (event, place) {
    console.log(place.formatted_address);
});
```

---

Html:

```
<input ng-model="locationGo" type="text" g-places-autocomplete>
<input ng-model="locationTop" type="text" g-places-autocomplete>
```

I am getting selected location from both input fields but I want to know  which input filed was selected.